# Laravel cookie session lifetime

Tags: session, cookies, laravel, lifetime

I used my Laravel as a OAuth2 client, and I need to keep token i cookies. So, I set driver to cookie and keep default value for lifetime 120

When any user check remember me on login, I tried to change lifetime with code:

```
    $lifetime = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;// one year
    Config::set('session.lifetime', $lifetime);
```

But without success. In any another controller I checked value of lifetime and every time I get default value.

```
\Log::info(\Config::get('session.lifetime'));
```

**Edit #1:**

It is enough?

```
if(Input::has('rememberMe')) {
   $lifetime = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // one year
   Session::put('Expires', $lifetime);
}
```

**Edit #2:**

I put acess_token key on the same way as Expires in example above, like:

```
public function signin() {

    /**
     * Code for getting *client_code* and *client_state* from API server
     */

    $access_token = $this->provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', $form_data);

    // $access_token is object and contain all data (access_token, refresh_token, expires)
    Session::put('access_token', $access_token);
    Session::put('refresh_token', $access_token->refreshToken);
    Session::put('token_expires', $access_token->expires);

    if(Input::has('rememberMe')) {
       $lifetime = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // one year
       Session::put('expires', $lifetime);
    }


    return Response....

}
```

This is the 'default' Laravel session (I changed driver from *file* to *cookie* in /app/config/session.php). I know life time should be set in /app/config/session.php file, but as you can see I need longer life time for Remember me option

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the token into the cookies? You can only change the cookie's expiry during when you set it, and it's per cookie value.

Comment: If you want "remember me" functionality you're better off using Sentry. https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry

Comment: No, this is the client without database ;)

Answer (score 7):

Actually when you are setting the value like this in a `Controller`:

```
$lifetime = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;// one year
Config::set('session.lifetime', $lifetime);
```

It's not updating the value in the file, instead it sets it for the current request only (in memory) and when you check the value using this from another Controller/Request like this:

```
Config::get('session.lifetime');
```

You are getting the value from the original value from file system. It's mentioned in the documentation as given below:

> Configuration values that are set at run-time are only set for the
>   current request, and will not be carried over to subsequent requests.

Comment: OK. And how I can set lifetime for 'current' session/logged user?

Comment: From the `app/config/session.php` file to make it persistence.

Comment: Yea, but for all session. Some of the user want to keep session/cookie for the long time, some does not want. It is confused for me. How can I made different cookie for different parameters, after user get success from API server about successfully logged?

Answer (score 3):

Since it seems to be OK to use cookies as the session driver in your case, you could set the session lifetime to one year in `/app/config/session.php` by default and store the expiration date of the **cookie** along with the token in the session. That would allow you to control artificially the validity of the cookie.

Basically, your `signin` method could look like this:

```
public function signin() {

    /**
     * Code for getting *client_code* and *client_state* from API server
     */

    $access_token = $this->provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', $form_data);

    // $access_token is object and contain all data (access_token, refresh_token, expires)
    Session::put('access_token', $access_token);
    Session::put('refresh_token', $access_token->refreshToken);
    Session::put('token_expires', $access_token->expires);

    if (Input::has('rememberMe')) {
       $expires = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // one year
    } else {
       $expires = time() + 60 * 60 * 2; // two hours
    }

    Session::put('cookie_expires', $expires);

    return Response....

}
```

Then, any time you want to use the `access_token`, you would check that `cookie_expires` isn't past first (and if it is, redirect the user to the login page after clearing the session, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea where the `Session::put('expires', $lifetime);` will be used. To me, it seems like a normal cookie variable, not actual lifetime associated with any cookie.

You will need to set the cookie lifetime before your cookies are set, and do it the way that Laravel knows you're setting a new cookie lifetime value.

```
public function signin() {

    $access_token = $this->provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', $form_data);

    if (!$access_token) {
        return Response... // Respond some other way if authentication failed.
    }

    // Check rememberMe first so you can set the right session.lifetime before setting any cookies.
    if(Input::has('rememberMe')) {
       $lifetime = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // one year
       Config::set('session.lifetime', $lifetime);
    }

    Session::put('access_token', $access_token);
    Session::put('refresh_token', $access_token->refreshToken);
    Session::put('token_expires', $access_token->expires);

    return Response....
}
```

I also took the chance to add `if (!$access_token) {` before setting the cookie since you won't always be authenticating successfully.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried something like this yesterday, but without success :( This is not override session lifetime as we expect.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070400/laravel-4-remember-me-expire-time

Comment: Here's another idea: `Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('access_token', $access_token, $lifetime));` (adapted from https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/master/Guard.php)