# Laravel stores too much sessions for 20 users

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.5

I set session to database

and I noticed laravel store alot of sessions I only have 20 users

I made full project search to find where I store session and I find one place when the user access the app it remove old sessions and renew them.

```
/*store token in session*/
    $token = $this->jesonToArray($response)['access_token'];

    if ( ! is_null($token))
    {
        Session()->flush();
        Session::put('token', $token);
        Session::put('shop', $this->apiKeys['SHOP_NAME']);
    } else if ( ! is_null(Session::get('token')))
    {
        return Session::get('token');
    }
```

In 2 monthes laravel stored over 10 thousands sessions

the session lifetime is 18 days

```
'lifetime' => 26200
```

is this normal ??

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw, I believe you can configure what Laravel uses as the lifetime for Cookies. You can use

```
Config::set('session.lifetime', ...)
```

**Sources**

[Laravel cookie session lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317313/laravel-cookie-session-lifetime#24317485)

Comment: lifetime is not the issue  I have 20 user  it should have 20 session lets says laravel uses sessions it will have 100 sessions for 20 users   but in fact in one day  it reach to 1200 stored sessions ??? is that normal ?

Comment: I think it might depend on the users and datetime of each session. Unless I misunderstand your situation, an issue like a single user logging in multiple times on one day is possible. It looks like it PUTs for each unique token and each token might only last 15 or 30 minutes for user sessions unless configured differently.