# Laravel Login Session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, session-cookies

If I want to extend the login session *(via remember me)* of the users, is this the only config I should modify? So if I want one day it will be 60x24=1440?

```
//Session Lifetime in sesssion.php
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look at the comment above `lifetime` option:

> Here you may specify the **number of minutes** that you wish the session
>   to be allowed to remain idle before it expires.

So, just set it to:

```
'lifetime' => 1440,
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember me is a function of authentication utilizing a cookie and a special column in the user table.   It has nothing to do with session lifetime.

Remember me functionality is described here:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication

With a key enabling element being:

> Of course, your users table must include the string remember_token
>   column, which will be used to store the "remember me" token.

If what you mean is that you want to limit the lifetime of the remember me cookie, then you have to override the default lifetime of the cookie.

A way to do that without altering the core [was described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070400/laravel-4-remember-me-expire-time), at least for version 4, but I would suspect since it is basically hacking HTTP header values, that it would still work for 5.